# How do I solve a linear programming problem using excel functions

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I have an n x m matrix where the sum of rows and columns are specified. How do I get excel to fill numbers automatically? The solution should start from corner cell and keep on filling numbers to match the summation of rows and columns to the predefined value.

I have tried using solver for this but I cannot set the priority in it. I need the solution to start from the corner cell and then process one row and column at a time.

It should also prioritize the columns. in case columns are all satisfied and rows are not. It could just fill rest of the cells with 0.

[image]

Comment: Tell us more about your problem and why you want to prioritize (and why this zigzag pattern, and do you require an integer solution, etc.). Note that it's fairly easy to find a possible matrix given margins, if the sums are positive, and if you don't require integers array elements: let `a(i,j)=rowsum(i)*colsum(j)/total`, where total is the sums of rows or columns (they must be the same).

Comment: Yours seems to be an `nxm` problem, as there are 4 columns and 6 rows in your sample data.

Comment: sorry , I edited that . can i get the result for an n cross m matrix